# How to implement about calculating weighted average if it's without for loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-2.x

This is my code as the following:

```
students = [{'name': 'Tom',
             'subjects': {'math': 50,
                          'english': 100,
                          'science': 72}},
            {'name': 'Alex',
             'subjects': {'math': 100,
                          'english': 90,
                          'science': 95}}]

weighting_coefficient = {'math': 2,
                         'english': 10,
                         'science': 8}

total = sum(weighting_coefficient.values())

for index, student in enumerate(students):
    subjects = student['subjects']
    weighting_score = 0
    for subject, score in subjects.items():
        weighting_score += weighting_coefficient[subject] * score
    students[index]['weighted_average'] = float(weighting_score)/total

print students
```

The result:

```
[{'name': 'Tom',
  'subjects': {'english': 100, 'math': 50, 'science': 72},
  'weighted_average': 83.8},
 {'name': 'Alex',
  'subjects': {'english': 90, 'math': 100, 'science': 95},
  'weighted_average': 93.0}]
```

I am sure to complete the calculation, but is it available to implement the codes if I don't use `foor-loop` to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use a `for` loop? If you know the length of each array you can just use manual [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)

Comment: I think using `for-loop` is so lengthy. Or maybe using python built-in function can reduce the lines.

Comment: I don't understand. Loops are used to reduce the amount of times you repeat code, _reducing_ length. Are you trying to make the program _shorter_?

Comment: @Arc676 Yes, I want to make the program shorter.

Comment: Take a look about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kevin Guan for your great tip (helped me advance my own "Python career")

Using List Comprehension, as suggested:

```
students = [{'name': 'Tom',
         'subjects': {'math': 50,
                      'english': 100,
                      'science': 72}},
        {'name': 'Alex',
         'subjects': {'math': 100,
                      'english': 90,
                      'science': 95}}]

weighting_coefficient = {'math': 2,
                     'english': 10,
                     'science': 8}

total = sum(weighting_coefficient.values())

for student in students:
    student['weighted_average'] = float( sum( [student['subjects'][subj] * weighting_coefficient[subj] for subj in student['subjects'].keys() ] ) ) / total

print students
```

The code looks messy at first, but you could create some more variables to hold key information (and make `weighting_coefficients` shorter).

I've tested both with the original data set and one extra (not included here but the results matched using both OP's method and my method).